# Can't exclude ferries, tolls or motorways on the mapbox route

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using [mapbox-gl-directions](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions), version: `4.0.2`. I want to exclude tolls, ferries or motorways. Here is a documentation: [API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#retrieve-directions) and it says you can pass `exclude` parameter:[image: exclude property]
But while passing it like this, it doesn't work:

```
new MapboxDirections({
      accessToken: this.accessToken,
      unit: 'metric',
      profile: 'mapbox/driving',
      flyTo: false,
      styles,
      controls: {
        inputs: false,
        instructions: false,
        profileSwitcher: false
      },
      exclude: 'ferry'
    });
```

Has anyone any idea how to pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a [pull request](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/pull/233) and it was merged successfully. Released under version: [4.0.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the mapbox-gl-directions plugin doesn't support `exclude=`. You've done the right thing raising [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/issues/232).